# unable to find user sail: no matching entries in passwd file

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-sail

Please I'm working with Laravel on Docker, trying to run the `sail` command

`./vendor/bin/sail composer install`

in order to manage the laravel packages and install Tailwind CSS but it keeps sowing this message:

> unable to find user sail: no matching entries in passwd file

I wonder what I'm missing! here is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '2.0'
services:
 
  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: abdelazizmirasoft/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
      - ./php/laravel.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/laravel.ini
    networks:
      - app-network
 
  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver-upwork
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network
 
  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.32
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network
 
#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
 
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

my `.env` file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:5ndGfShEF7w6wfnnzMlGrG7A9IFOJrlh9G7VVw0BTgM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_SERVICE=app

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=upwork_clone
DB_USER=upwork_user
DB_PASSWORD=p@$sw0rd

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

and the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:8.0.5-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json into the working directory
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/html/
 
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
 
# Install dependencies for the operating system software
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    libzip-dev \
    unzip \
    git \
    libonig-dev \
    curl
 
# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 
# Install extensions for php
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
 
# Install composer (php package manager)
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
 
# Copy existing application directory contents to the working directory
COPY . /var/www/html
 
# Assign permissions of the working directory to the www-data user
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data \
        /var/www/html/storage \
        /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache
 
# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server (for FastCGI Process Manager)
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Anyone can help with that?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try a `RUN useradd sail` in your Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel provides [Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail), a built-in solution for running your Laravel project using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/).

[Laravel Sail](https://github.com/laravel/sail) is a Docker development environment included by default in Laravel since version 8. It allows you to quickly get a PHP development environment up and running, tailored for running Laravel applications with built-in support for NPM / Node.

So in order to build your containers properly I recommend to read about this article: [How To Build a Responsive About Me Page with Laravel, Sail, and Tailwind CSS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-laravel-application-with-laravel-sail-and-tailwind-css)